# Condition on $f$ to preserve connectedness under preimage

Tags: real-analysis

We know that it is not true that the preimage of a connected set thru a continuous function is still connected. For example consider $x\mapsto\log|x|$; the preimage of $\Bbb R$ is then $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.
So I was wondering what conditions are sufficient for this to happen for a generic continuous mapping between topological spaces
$$
f:X\to Y\;.
$$
Is for example to be an embedding a sufficient condition?

Comment: Monotonic functions, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but if you look at projective morphisms between projective varieties, the Stein factorization decomposes such a morphism as a composition of a fiber space and a finite map. The fiber space has connected fibers, and the finite map does not. I do not think that fiber spaces satisfy the condition you want, however.

Comment: +1 for nice problem.

Comment: @Joe, Embedding is not a sufficient condition. Example: Embed $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ in $ℝ$ via identity. The preimage of $ℝ$ is not connected.